# Laravel Passing Additional Parameter To Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I need to pass an additional parameter($uid) from my index.blade.php to my edit.blade.php by clicking on a button.

My index.blade.php:

```
<a href="{!!action('FlyersController@edit', ['id' => Auth::user()->id, 'uid' => 1])!!}" type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-info vorlageBtn card-link">Edit </a>
```

My FlyersController:

```
public function edit($id, $uid)
{

    return view('backend.flyers.edit')->withUid($uid);
}
```

With the code above I get an error: "Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\FlyersController::edit()"

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: why don't you link a route instead?

Answer (score 2):

The error is not throwing from the action method. It is coming from route for that URL.

Check the URL for passing argument to the the controller.

If this is the your desire URL `localhost:8000/backend/flyers/10/edit?%24uid=1` then the second argument is in `$request` variable not in controller function argument.

Comment: this is my route Route::resource('backend/flyers', 'FlyersController');

Comment: you are using resource routing the second argument is in query string so it is retrieve from the Request variable like $request->uid make sure to add Request variable in controller action

Answer (score 1):

You should pass an array into [`action()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-action) helper:

```
action('FlyersController@edit', ['id' => Auth::user()->id, 'uid' => 1])
```

Comment: I also tried this. With the same result. By the way, this is the url I am redirected to after htitting the button "http://localhost:8000/backend/flyers/10/edit?%24uid=1". The uid is passed, but the FlyersController still makes trouble

Comment: Also with <a href="{!!action('FlyersController@edit', ['id' => Auth::user()->id, '$uid' => 1])!!}" type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-info vorlageBtn card-link"> I still get an error witj missing argument 2

Comment: This does not work for me. Laravel 5.8

Answer (score 1):

Ok, 
the only way I can solve this is by using the following in My FlyersController:

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id)
{

    return view('backend.flyers.edit')->withRequest($request);
}
```

and access then the uid with {{request->uid}} in my view.

If anybody has a better solution for this, let me know.

Comment: Not sure why you would need a better solution. This is a very good way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code

```
return view('backend.flyers.edit', ['var1' => $var1, 'var2' => $var2]);
```

That will pass two or more variables to your view

Comment: OP wants to pass parameters to a controller, not to a view.

Comment: Same result. The Controller still doesn't know about  the param